# iOS gesture recognition and processing

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, gesture

I have transparent UIImageView and UIScrollView under it , I want the UIImageView to recognize and process swipe gesture right and left , and pass the scroll up an down to the UIScrollView
How can I do it?

I added the swipe gestures to the image view and handle them, but I didn't find a way to pass the scrolling from the UIImage to UIScroll

Answer (score 0):

You could could set the [userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) property of the scroll view to `NO` and add several gesture recognizers to handle the different events (horizontal and vertical scrolling).

Comment: I need the uiimage(transparent image) to be at the top, so my problem is in passing the scroll gesture from imageview to scrollview

Comment: Just set the `userInteractionEnabled` of both to `NO` and the gestures will passed down the responder chain. Then the scroll view can catch those events with gesture recognizer.

Comment: every thing stop responding when I set userinteraction disabled
(BTW the scrollView is WebView)